# cannot re-add item to basket (array) after it is removed

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a basket (an array) in my PHP form, where users can add their selected movies to it.
The image below, may show the situation better:

[image]

**Problem:**
As can be seen in the image, user can click on the garbage image to remove a movie from the list. Now, the problem is that if he/she would like to re-add this removed film to the selected list again, the message is shown *"This movie is already in the list".*, while it should be shown ONLY IF the movie is not in the list NOW!

This is my code (form.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var master_basket = new Array();
var selectedMovies = {};

$(document).ready(function () {
/// SOME CODES UNRELATED TO MY QUESTION ....

 function get_index_of_item(movie_name) {
for (var i = 0; i < master_basket.length; i++) {
    if (master_basket[i].movie_name === movie_name){
        return i;
    }
 }
 return -1;
}

function addToBasket(item) {
   master_basket.push(item);
   showBasketObjects();
}

function showBasketObjects() {
   $("#basket_content").empty();
   $.each(master_basket, function(k,v) {
         var name_and_year = v.movie_name;
         console.log(v.movie_name);
         console.log(v.movie_year);          

         $("#basket_content").append("<div class='item_list'>" + v.movie_name + "<a class='remove_link' href='" + name_and_year + "'><img width='20' src='http://i61.tinypic.com/4n9tt.png'></a></div>");
   });

   $(".remove_link").on('click', function (e) {       
     var name_year = $(this).attr("href");
     console.log(name_year);

     var index = get_index_of_item(name_year[0]);
     console.log(index);

    if (index !== -1) {
     master_basket.splice(index, 1);
     console.log(master_basket);
     $(this).closest('.item_list').remove();
    } else {
           console.log("DEBUG: NO ITEM IN THE LIST");
    }
     return false;
  });
}
```

and this is my **UPDATED** searchfilm.php:

```
<?php
// QUERY DB
 while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
      ?> 
     <tr>
         <td><img class='imdbImage' id="image" src='imdbImage.php?url=<?php echo $row['posterLink']; ?>' alt="" /></td>

         <td><label id='year'><?php echo $row['year']; ?> </label></td>

         <td><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/<?php echo urlencode($row['ImdbId']); ?>"><?php echo $row['movieName']; ?></a></td>

        <td><a href="javascript:addmovie('<?php echo $row['movieName'], "_", $row['year']; ?>')" class="add">Add to list</a></td>
     </tr> 
      <?php
       endwhile;
      ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addmovie(movieName) {       

    var obj = {
              "movie_name":movieName
              };

    var index = parent.window.opener.get_index_of_item(movieName);

         if(index === -1) {
                parent.window.opener.addToBasket(obj);  
         }  else {
                alert("This movie is already in the selected list");
         }
    }
 </script>
```

Could someone kindly help me know how to fix it?

Comment: have you no means of debugging? Which IDE are you using? In the worst case, with no IDE (yeuch!), you can throw a few alert() into your code to see what is in the basket when.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I'm confused. You have `addToBasket()` and `addmovie()`. One is pushing items into the `master_basket` Array, and the other is adding them as named properties on the `master_basket` Array object. Why have both?

Comment: In any case, you're adding the object to the Array, but then trying to get its `.indexOf()` using its name and year. That isn't going to work. It has no way of knowing that the string should be compared to the `movie_name/movie_year` properties. You'll need to manually search the array.

Comment: @sixfingeredman: I have addToBasket function in the main page of the form, where there is a textbox and search button. `addmovie` is the function I used in the other page (where there is DB queries), which contains more codes if you see.. Do you think I did it by mistake?

Comment: @sixfingeredman: I think the problem is because I remove `.item_list'` div, while the movieName is still in the master_basket..  so, I guess I have to remove it from basket list instead of removing div.. , what do u think?

Comment: It seems like you should remove this line `master_basket[movieName] = obj;` and then just create a function that searches the basket for the movie/year in the array. You can use that function in `addmovie()` in place of your `.hasOwnProperty()` check, as well as in the `remove` handler. Have the function return the index or `-1` if not found just like `.indexOf()` would

Comment: @sixfingeredman: Sorry, but I didn't understand well what I have to do, could you please explain more in detail?

Comment: I'll add another answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.indexOf()` search is looking for a string of `"The Matrix_1999"`, but the basket doesn't hold strings. It holds objects with all the movie info. So your `.indexOf()` was returning `-1`.

You need a function that will search for the right object in the basket based on the name and year that you give it.

Also, there's no need to add the name/year as properties to the basket.

```
var master_basket = new Array();

/*** This will receive the movie name/year, 
     and return the index or -1 if not found ***/
function get_index_of_item(movie_name, movie_year) {
    for (var i = 0; i < master_basket.length; i++) {
        if (master_basket[i].movie_name == movie_name &&
            master_basket[i].movie_year == movie_year {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function addToBasket(item) {
   master_basket.push(item);
   showBasketObjects();
}

// We need to pass along the movie name and year so it can be used to
//  fetch the right index from the array.
function showBasketObjects() {
   $("#basket_content").empty();
   $.each(master_basket, function(k, v) {
         var name_and_year = v.movie_name + "_" + v.movie_year;

         $("#basket_content").append("<div class='item_list'>" + 
                                      v.movie_name + 
                                      "<a class='remove_link' href='" + 
                                      name_and_year + 
                                      "'><img width='20' src='http://i61.tinypic.com/4n9tt.png'></a></div>");
   });

 $(".remove_link").on('click', function (e) {
     // Split the `href` on the `_` character to get the name and year
     var name_year = $(this).attr("href").split("_");

     // The split gave us an Array. The name is at the first index,
     //  and the year is at the second
     var index = get_index_of_item(name_year[0], name_year[1]);

     // We check to see if it returned `-1`, and if not, we remove it
     if (index !== -1) {
         master_basket.splice(index, 1);
         console.log(master_basket);
         $(this).closest('.item_list').remove();
     } else {
         console.log("DEBUG: For some reason it was not in the list");
     }
     return false;
  });
}
```

---

```
// I think the `movieName` is getting `"The Matrix_1999"`, so split it on `"_"`
function addmovie(movieName) {
    var name_and_year = movieName.split("_");

    var obj = {
          "movie_name":name_and_year[0],
          "movie_year":name_and_year[1]
    };

    // Use the function to see if the item is already in the list
    var index = parent.window.opener.get_index_of_item(movieName, year);

    // If it returned `-1`, we can add it.
    if(index === -1) {
         parent.window.opener.addToBasket(obj); 
    } else {
         alert("This movie is already in the selected list");
    }
}
```